# Associative array with member function

Tags: oracle, associative-array, member-functions

Can we have member function for an associative array in Oracle?

```
DECLARE
TYPE country_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50)
INDEX BY VARCHAR2(5);
```

and I want to add a member function as `to_char()` that will print all the items in its own list (just like java `toString()` for maps/arraylist).

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a member function on an `Associative array`. This is only possible on `OBJECT` Types.

You must write the function using the "classic" structured programing.